# How to get post author name in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, posts, hook-wordpress

In WordPress I need to fetch name of author who created post using `author_id`.
How can I find `author_name` ?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author/) ...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> You can use [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/), to get author data.

```
echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found that this function is depricated.

Comment: @RakhiPrajapati: oo isit? I did't knew neither the official doc say anything about it.

Comment: `get_the_author_meta()` is not depreciated. You might be thinking of `get_the_author()`

Comment: Where do `$author_id`'s value come from? This is confusing.

Comment: @Akshaykn `$author_id` refers to the user ID which belongs to `wp_users.id` field.

Comment: If you are looking for the author name of the current post (say on a single.php page) you can use `get_the_author_meta('display_name', get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )` to dynamically get the value of $author_id.

Answer (score 10):

This should work like charm

```
<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
```

For more detailed information.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author

Answer (score 6):

Use below code in single.php or the relevant page you want author name

```
<?php get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id ); ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

When used in the WordPress Custom REST API endpoint you can do it like this:

```
function customrestapiplugin_getpost( $slug ) {
    $args = [
        'name' => $slug['slug'],
        'post_type' => 'post'
    ];

    $post = get_posts($args);
    
    $data[$i]['id'] = $post[0]->ID;
        $data['title'] = $post[0]->post_title;
        $data['content'] = $post[0]->post_content;
        $data['excerpt'] = $post[0]->post_excerpt;
        $data['slug'] = $post[0]->post_name;
        $data['date'] = $post[0]->post_date;
        $data['link'] = get_permalink($post[0]->ID);
        $data['author'] = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post[0]->post_author);
        $data['featured_image']['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post[0]->ID, 'thumbnail');
        $data['featured_image']['medium'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post[0]->ID, 'medium');
        $data['featured_image']['large'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post[0]->ID, 'large');

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add This code in single-post.php

```
<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
```

I hope this will work !!

Comment: duplicate of above answer .

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a seamless solution on how to get an author of a post in WordPress, this is another lightweight method.

```
global $wpdb;

    $post_id = 12; // your post id
    
    $post_author_id = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_author FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE ID = %d ", $post_id ) );
    
    $author =  new WP_User( $post_author_id );
    
    $display_name = $author->display_name;
    
    $avartar = get_avatar( $post_author_id, 30 ); // get_avatar( userid, size )
    
    $author_url = get_author_posts_url( $post_author_id );
```